# Advise for docker ich777/thunderbird

Tags: docker, thunderbird, nas, synology

I try to install on synology 220+ this docker ich777/thunderbird

Docker config:

docker run --name Thunderbird -d 
-p 8080:8080 
--env 'THUNDERBIRD_V=latest' 
--env 'THUNDERBIRD_LANG=en-US' 
--env 'CUSTOM_RES_W=1280' 
--env 'CUSTOM_RES_H=768' 
--env 'UID=1026' 
--env 'GID=100' 
--env 'UMASK=000' 
--env 'DATA_PERM=770' 
--volume volume1/docker/thunderbird/mnt/cache/appdata/thunderbird - i create this folder  structure
ich777/thunderbird

Every time i recieve this error: "volume1/docker/thunderbird/mnt/cache/appdata/thunderbird" includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed. If you intended to pass a host directory, use absolute path.

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

> If you intended to pass a host directory, use absolute path.

The excerpt quoted above is the crucial message here.

**How to fix**:

`--volume volume1/docker/thunderbird/mnt/cache/appdata/thunderbird` should be `--volume /volume1/docker/thunderbird/mnt/cache/appdata/thunderbird` (note the slash before `volume1`)

Explanation:

- an absolute path begins with `/` and a relative path does not
- the docker `--volume` flag usually is followed by three fields separated by the `:` character of the form `name:path:options` for example `my-volume-name:/path/to/volume:ro` which would be a *read-only* volume named **my-volume-name** stored at `/path/to/volume`.

  - The third *options* field is optional and can be  omitted.
  - The first field, name, may also be omitted (this is an anonymous volume).
- by specifying only one field, this implies you are omitting both the *name* and the *options* and **only providing a path**. However, the path must be an absolute path which begins with `/`
- volume names cannot have slashes in them, which is why the text which does not begin with a slash cannot be a volume name, either

Comment: Thaks a lot. Was first time trying to run a docker container inside Synology Server and was ponering how to make it run. Your comment helped a lot.